# Shell script variable & loop

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I want to print the largest number passed in on the command line but I am not sure how to assign a variable correctly.

What is the correct way to solve this issue?

```
#!/bin/sh
x=0
for var in "$@";
do 
if [ $var -gt $x ]; then
$x=$var       #this does not work
fi

done
echo "Largest number: $x"
```

Comment: To assign a value to a variable you do `var=$something`. Change `$x=$var` to `x=$var`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is `$x=$var`. It should be `x=$var`. You can think of it as `$x` is the value contained the in variable `x` so you don't want to assign to value of `x` but to `x` itself.

```
#!/bin/sh
x=0
for var in "$@"; do
    if [ "$var" -gt "$x" ]; then
        x="$var"
    fi
done
echo "Largest number: $x"
```

---

Here is an alternative script using some core-utils that will work with negative numbers:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Largest: $(printf '%i\n' $@ | sort -n | tail -n 1)"
```

Comment: Brilliant, thought I was close @sudo_O